# Container docker não consegue acessar servidor LDAP

Tags: docker, .net-core

tenho uma aplicação que precisa fazer acesso a um servidor LDAP (Active Directory) e ao rodar a aplicão localmente está funcionando normalmente, entretanto ao rodar a aplicação dentro de um container do docker ela não consegue acessar o servidor do Active Directory.
Quando eu executo um ping dentro do container o servidor LDAP é alcançado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse aqui é o método que faz a conexão com o Active Directory

```cs
        /// <summary>
        /// Construtor da classe
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="configuration">Parâmetro de configuração</param>
        public ActiveDirectoryClient(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<ActiveDirectoryClient> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _configuration = configuration;
            _domain = _configuration["LDAPAdress"];
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Tenta conectar com o ActiveDirectory até uma quantidade de vezes e um intervalo de tempo fornecido em segundos
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="attemps">Número de tentativas</param>
        /// <param name="retryInterval">Intervalo de tempo entre as tentativas em segundos</param>
        /// <returns>Retorna o contexto do Active Directory</returns>
        /// <exception cref="CustomException">Lançada quando não é possível se conectar com o ActiveDiretory</exception>
        private PrincipalContext TryConnectActiveDirectory(int attemps, double retryInterval)
        {
            while (attemps > 0)
            {
                _context = null;
                var isRetry = false;


                _logger.LogCritical(_domain);
                try
                {
                    _context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, _domain);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    isRetry = true;
                    attemps--;
                    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(retryInterval));
                }

                if (isRetry || _context.Container == null)
                {
                    attemps--;
                    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(retryInterval));
                }
            }

            _logger.LogCritical(_domain);

            if (_context == null)
            {
                throw new CustomException(HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable, "Não foi possível conectar-se com o servidor");
            }

            return _context;
        }
```

Esse aqui é o arquivo com as configurações so projeto

```js
{
  "LDAPAdress": "10.10.2.1",
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Estou rodando a imagem buildada na porta 60331 que está mapeada para o porta 80. Ela está funcionando pois tenha acesso ao swagger

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Executei um tcpdump -i eth0 port 389 para listar somente as requisições que foram para servidor ldap, mas não tive nenhum resultado, mas se eu executar a aplicação localmente eu consigo obter as requsições.

Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: se vc enxerga a máquina não poderia ser um problema de segurança, certificado por exemplo?

Comment: Eu executei um curl para endereço do servidor do active directory passando a porta 389 e não possando porta nenhuma (acredito que ele utilize a porta 80) e a requisição acontece. Aparecentemente não está ocorrendo a requisição por meio da aplicação:
````
$ curl 10.10.2.1
```
e
````
$ curl 10.10.2.1:389
```
, mesmo que fosse problema de segurança eu pelo menos conseguiria snifar o pacote não?

Comment: sim, se for segurança tá no nivel do protocolo/autenticação, então um sniffer tipo um wireshark ia pegar o pacote chegando no ldap. se não pega, pode até ser um problema de map de portas

Comment: Uma coisa que eu tentei foi fazer forward da porta 20000 do meu host para o endereço 10.10.2.1:389 e o container faz a requisição para host.docker.internal:20000. Utilizei o tcpdump para fazer sniff dentro do container e não foi apresentado nenhum pacote e usei o wireshark no meu host e também não foi pega nenhum pacote. Entrentando se eu fizer um `curl host.docker.internal:20000` tanto o wireshark que está executando no host quando o tcpdump que está executando no container consegue capturar os pacotes

Comment: Coloquei para logar a mensagem da exceção lançada no try/catch e descobri o problema não está em conseguir acessar o servidor LDAP: "System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement is not supported on this platform", o meu container é ubuntu 18.04 enquanto o meu host é windows 10

Comment: deve ser isso mesmo, mas que coisa :( vai precisar de um container windows então

Comment: Irei fazer um serviço com node para fazer essas operações com o active directory com a lib activedirectory e rodar em outro container, Não sei se é ideial, mas parece mais prático que criar todas as operações necessárias com alguma biblioteca de ldap para .net core